# Why my DateTime is giving this error ? in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-test

Im trying to get a data from firebase witch is String type  . like this format (yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm) and im trying to pares the String to Datetime but it gives me error please can anyone tell me how to solve the problem ...

code :

```
 var retriveDateTime = database_Reference
      .child("users")
      .child(_wifiObject.macAddress)
      .child(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now()));

 if (retriveDateTime != null) {
      retriveDateTime.once().then((value) {
        String formatedtime = value.value['startingTime'];
        startup_time = DateTime.parse(formatedtime);
      });
      insertDataToDatabase();
    } else {
      startup_time = DateTime.now();
      insertDataToDatabase();
    }
```

The Error I get :

```
E/flutter ( 7155): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format
E/flutter ( 7155): 2021-07-29 – 23:46
/flutter ( 7155): #1      _MyHomePageState.initState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
```

package:alfurat_app/main.dart:16

when I click on the error its taking me to this :

```
 startup_time = DateTime.parse(formatedtime);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to official docs. There are few String format support. check [DateTime/parse.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)

in your case `DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')` is not supported. replace with `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')`.

Examples of accepted strings:

```
"2012-02-27"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z"
"20120227 13:27:00"
"20120227T132700"
"20120227"
"+20120227"
"2012-02-27T14Z"
"2012-02-27T14+00:00"
"-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.
"2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"
```

Comment: ty very much i endup adding this code here

Comment: String formatedtime = value.value['startingTime'];
            String datefixed = formatedtime.substring(0, 10);
            String timeFixed = formatedtime.substring(12, 18);
            String finalTimeFixed = datefixed + timeFixed;
            print(DateTime.parse(finalTimeFixed)); //2021-07-29 – 23:46
            startup_time = DateTime.parse(finalTimeFixed);

Comment: then i will be happy if my time was useful by accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

i find out the proplem was with the formatted datetime in the datebase
was like this (2021-07-29 – 23:46)

the problem with the - between the date and the time so i end up useing this

```
 String formatedtime = value.value['startingTime'];
        String datefixed = formatedtime.substring(0, 10);
        String timeFixed = formatedtime.substring(12, 18);
        String finalTimeFixed = datefixed + timeFixed;
        print(DateTime.parse(finalTimeFixed)); //2021-07-29 – 23:46
        startup_time = DateTime.parse(finalTimeFixed);
```